# Why can't Java find this file in System32?

Tags: java, io, system32

So I tried removing a folder in my System32 folder, but java can't seem to find it ...

```
    File gwxFolder = new File("C:/Windows/System32/GWX");

    System.out.println(gwxFolder.getPath());
    if(gwxFolder.exists()){
        IO.deleteFolder(gwxFolder);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find your folder.");
    }
```

Comment: Does the folder actually exist?

Comment: You're probably running this on a 64-bit system. You need to check in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` as well.

Comment: I manually made that folder so I am 100% sure it exists

Comment: what is the error you are getting? How are you running the Java App? What are the permissions on the folder?

Comment: I don't get any errors, I just get my MessageBox ("Can't find your folder"). I am running it from Eclipse. I just tested it with another folder and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't tell you precisely what is wrong, I may be able to tell you how to get an answer.

java.io.File is old and obsolete.  It was part of Java 1.0, and many of its methods are unreliable for various reasons, often returning an uninformative magic value like 0 or null instead of throwing an exception that actually describes the nature of the failure.

The File class has been replaced with [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).  You can obtain a Path instance with [Paths.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) or [File.toPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--).

Once you have a Path, most operations on it are performed with the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.  In particular, you probably want either [Files.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) or [Files.isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-).

You may also want to consider deleting that directory yourself, using [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-), so if it fails, you'll get a useful and informative exception:

```
Path gwxFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Windows\\System32\\GWX");

if (Files.exists(gwxFolder)) {
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(gwxFolder, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                             BasicFileAtttributes attributes)
            throws IOException {
                Files.delete(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                                      IOException e)
            throws IOException {
                if (e == null) {
                    Files.delete(dir);
                }
                return super.postVisitDirectory(dir, e);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace, true));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, stackTrace);
    }
}
```